# VBA doesn't update Excel links

Tags: vba, excel

I am new here. Thanks to everyone who is making a contribution, and sharing their knowledge.

I have a whole network of Excel files linked between themselves. At the beginning of every month, I am making copies of each file, reflecting the month and year in the name of each file. 
In order not to link them one by one every month, I made a Macro following a simple logic. The Macro seems to work for most of the files, however, in one file, I encountered a problem.

Here is my code:

```
Dim MISWB As Workbook
Workbooks.Open Filename:="Y:\AM\20" & Godina & "\MIS_" & Godina & "\1MIS" & Godina & Mesec & ".xlsx", UpdateLinks:=0
Set MISWB = ActiveWorkbook

'*****INPUT*****
ChDir "Y:\AM\20" & Godina & "\INPUT_" & Godina
ActiveWorkbook.ChangeLink Name:="Y:\AM\20" & Godina & "\INPUT_" & Godina & "\INPUT" & Godina & PrethodenMesec & ".xlsx", NewName:= _
"INPUT" & Godina & Mesec & ".xlsx", Type:=xlExcelLinks

Where:
- Godina = year
- Mesec = current month
- Prethoden mesec = previous month
```

Well, when I have the file INPUT1709.xlsx open in the background, the Macro seems to be updating the link correctly.
When I don't have it open, and run the Macro, it doesn't change the link correctly, as if "INPUT1709.xlsx" doesn't exist. That's what it says when I click "OPEN SOURCE" from the "EDIT LINKS" tab.

In other files, the same code works without a problem, no matter if the INPUT file is open or not. For example:

```
'|***********************KWH***********************|
Dim KWHWB As Workbook
Workbooks.Open Filename:="Y:\AM\20" & Godina & "\KWH_" & Godina & "\KWh_" & Godina & Mesec & ".xls", UpdateLinks:=0
Set KWHWB = ActiveWorkbook

'*****INPUT*****
ChDir "Y:\AM\20" & Godina & "\INPUT_" & Godina
ActiveWorkbook.ChangeLink Name:="Y:\AM\20" & Godina & "\INPUT_" & Godina & "\INPUT" & Godina & PrethodenMesec & ".xlsx", NewName:= _
"INPUT" & Godina & Mesec & ".xlsx", Type:=xlExcelLinks
```

Any ideas what is going on here?

Thank you.

Comment: why do you set this variable `Set KWHWB = ActiveWorkbook` and then still refer to `ActiveWorkbook` in your code?

Comment: You are right, I will make the change, but I don't believe that's the problem with my code, do you?

Comment: no it is not the problem

Answer (score 0):

...and so it begins!  I apologize in advance if I make this problem sound worse it turns out to me, but I'll share how an identical situation turned our for me (and some possible fixes).

Honestly, reading your story triggered PTSD-like panic, of me being in the same situation: working for years with a plethora of interlinked spreadsheets, macros mashing together countless ever-changing ever-changing data sources... and **successfully** handing financial and analysis reporting for multiple corporations, working miracles with inconceivable amounts of data, stretching Excel to the sheer limits of capability.  It was a fragile yet awesome time of my life...  Read: [“Confessions of an Excel addict”](http://fortune.com/2012/10/01/confessions-of-an-excel-addict/)

…until things started going wrong.  Read: [“Is Business Overworking Excel?”](https://www.pcworld.com/article/143348/article.html)

Excel is very powerful but it has limitations, and when it's stretched too thin with too many interrelated dependencies, things like a minor unexpected change, or an otherwise-minor network hiccup or power fluctuation, can become the *butterfly that starts a hurricane* of headache, especially if your office is as dependent on this data & reporting as I suspect.  Read about: ["Data Degradation"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_degradation)

The workaround to this particular problem is a matter of patience and  troubleshooting skills.  I hope you have extra some time on your hands.

At least all but one the identical files are *potentially* okay; that narrows it down a LOT -- but does **not** necessarily mean that the problem is in *that* file.  (i.e., an error in a *different* file could be causing this one to act up.)  Did you try **skipping that file** and moving on the next file?  Delete and repopulate the data for the last week?  What changed?  Watch: [“Troubleshooting Theory”](https://youtu.be/MCsRGNSbWxk)

Beyond that, my next step would be to start big and narrow down the issue from there, so you’re dealing with the whole haystack at once.  By the sounds of it, even if the issue is only one cell, finding it is literally a *one in a million* shot. Read: [“Repair a corrupted workbook”](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Repair-a-corrupted-workbook-153a45f4)  (Microsoft’s only advice)

Make an extra backup of *everything* (all files, month-to-date and even prior if possible). This could be a pain, or a ***real*** pain, but since you have a separate “backup” copy of last month's data, make yet another copy of ALL of it, then go through the files one by one, *carefully* deleting all of last month's data, and once they’re all empty, copy *this month's data* into them.  Make sure you change any dates and links that need to be updated.  Before seeing if it worked, **triple-check** that you haven't missed anything in restoring this month's data to last month's files.  Memorize: [“The 3-2-1 Backup Rule”](https://www.google.ca/search?q=rule%20of%203%20backups)

Then pray to the Excel Gods while trying to run the processes you normally would.  If you're lucky, everything will run smoothly, with minimal to no data loss, nor overnights at the office.

If it worked, Congratulations!  But I'm not done yet!

Immediately make **yet another** backup set of this months’ (working) files, and store them nowhere near where they were. (I learned the hard way why copying a file to a different folder on the same drive is not a good idea.)  Afterwards, destroy the faulty copy of the files, and defrag every computer the data ever touches.

Finally, and **this is the most important step**, it's time to acknowledge that Excel has done its job well, but it's time to transition to a system that is intended for this type of data management.

In my experience, once "minor" issues like this start, it's only going to keep on happening.  "Workarounds" will be putting out fires more and more often.  Finally, I admitted to myself that it was time to transition everything to Microsoft Access.  Research: “When is it time to switch from Excel to Access?”  https://www.google.ca/searchq=when+is+it+time+to+switch+from+excel+to+access

Even if you don't have a lot of experience with Access and are looking at a sudden learning-curve, the change will be relatively easy since Excel and Access are made to work with each other, and soon you and everyone else in the company will be thankful you did, for it's increased usability & reliability, with an interface you put together to meet your exact needs, and expansion is never an issue. Read: “Top 10 reasons to use Access with Excel”  https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Top-10-reasons-to-use-Access-with-Excel

Access and I sort of had a "shotgun wedding" but we lived happily ever after.  Life at the office became easier than ever, I was learning new skills on the company’s dime, and things improved further when I finally convinced the higher-ups to shell out some real money for a top-shelf SQL Server package, redundant backups, “live” automatic reporting. Access was still there as the pretty front-end face, while SQL lived in the dark basement, alone, handling all the heavy lifting but never complaining.  Read: [“How to start any career without any experience”](https://www.google.ca/search?q=moving%20ahead%20in%20your%20data%20analysis%20career%20at%20any%20age&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&dcr=0&ei=inXLWaW9DYeIjwPwmr64DA)

In fact, the system ended up working out so well that the company decided to re-sell it to other similar companies, which basically consisted of nothing more than copy & pasting the existing files, changing a logo here or a report name there.

I was rewarded immensely for being such a forward-thinking superstar...  I never told them that I wasn't exactly *taking initiative* at the time, and even I didn't realize until later just how close we were to catastrophic data loss.   Read: [“Backup Overview”](http://www.dpbestflow.org/backup/backup-overview)

And we all lived happily ever after.  I like answering Excel questions online because after that, everything seems easy.     ...until today when I read your post.  Hopefully you can get this fixed up before you realize how close you might have been to having a *reallllly* bad day.

**Good Luck!**       Watch: [“My Old Friend Excel”](https://youtu.be/kOO31qFmi9A)(Original TV Commercial, 1992)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. I am working in the Controlling and Budgeting Department of a large production company. I am working with at least 50 different Excel files, each of which has at least 10 Worksheets, and all of these are linked together. I really cannot see how we can transition to a different platform. I simply cannot start making changes one at a time, because there is no one thing in this entire mess which is not connected to 30 other things. Individual files can't be repaired - I would put my life on it. I am trying to ease some processes with Macros, but here I am.